# Checkbox multiple checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i have problem to solve my script:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>View</td>
    <td>Insert</td>
    <td>Update</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Administrator</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkview chkview-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkitem chkitem-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkitem chkitem-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkitem chkitem-1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Free User</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkview chkview-2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkitem chkitem-2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkitem chkitem-2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkitem chkitem-2" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Demo: [DemoJS](http://jsfiddle.net/Rdk2G/4/)

is it possible if i checked true one of insert/edit/delete in row of administrator, checkbox view should be checked true?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? It is hard to understand. Also, you haven't posted any script here.

Comment: sorry @alKid, i have posted my script in this fiddle: [DemoJS] (http://jsfiddle.net/Rdk2G/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

Check this fiddle.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rdk2G/11/)

```
 $(function () {

    $('.chkview').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.chkitem').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $(".chkitem").change(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'), $items =$tr.find('.chkitem') ;
        $tr.find('.chkview').prop('checked', 'checked');
    });


});
```

As par your comment i update code. Please check it.

```
[Updated Filddle][2]
```

Write a script like this

```
    $(function () {

       $('.chkview').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.chkitem').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $(".chkitem").change(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'), $items =$tr.find('.chkitem') ;
        $tr.find('.chkview').prop('checked', $items.filter(':checked').length <= $items.length);       
        if($items.filter(':checked').length==0){
            $tr.find('.chkview').prop('checked','');
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: thanks @AB Vyas, but can i possible, example in one row of administrator i checked only insert and i uncheck insert, view should be unchecked false during insert/update/delete checked false.

Comment: Mean I am not getting you. can you please tell me in details.

Comment: sorry AB Vyas,your sample is working, but if i uncheck, all insert/update/delete should be View checked value is false. do you get it?

Comment: i have modify this sciprt. http://jsfiddle.net/Rdk2G/23/. problem is if i uncheck all item insert&update&delete should be View checked false/uncheck. can i posible do something like that?

Comment: @AdeZaenudin I Update the code and also give you one more fiddle. Please check it and if you satisfied with my answer please upvote my answer. :)